# How to add items in Listpicker in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to add items in Listpicker in WP7? using XAML. In simple way.

Comment: Drive-by downvoter care to explain?

Comment: It's a useless question, and he been linked examples and answers in his previous 5 nearly identical questions. If he wasn't a unregistered user, he would have a negative reputation for his constant repetitive useless questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/users/864837/sona , and http://stackoverflow.com/users/862918/sona

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen Didn't know unregistered users could reuse usernames. This person really likes the ListPicker, doesn't he? :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
<toolkit:ListPicker>
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="One"/>
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Two"/>
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Three"/>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

You can also customize the `ItemTemplate` to control the appearance of the content. [Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx) an article that explains how to do this.